# Why doesn't the system of linear equations have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Even though there are many similar questions I wasn't able to find anything good enough.
My question is why system where:

If A has row 1 + row 2 = row 3, doesn't have a solution and why it's non invertible.

I know the typical answer, saying that if A layer can be eliminated than the system has no solution because some information is redundant.

However, I tried proving that, by just trying to solve a system, thinking I won't be able to, but somehow find a way to get to row echelon form.

Here's how I did it:

Let's say we have:
[image]

I'll use augmented matrix.
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4 & -2 & 0\\
-4 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 5 & -3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $$

$$
Now we eliminate the bottom left value (-1). By multipling last row with 3 and subtracting from it row 1.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4 & -2 & 0\\
-4 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 19 & -11 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Now we eliminate value at spot 2,2 so 1. We di that by multipling last row with the 1/19 and subtracting from row 2.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4 & -2 & 0\\
-4 & 0 & -\dfrac{8}{19} & -\dfrac{3}{19} \\
0 & 19 & -11 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Now we eliminate finally we eliminate 3 and 4 from the first row using row 2 and row 3. We get.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-4 & 0 & -\dfrac{8}{19} & -\dfrac{3}{19} \\
0 & 19 & -11 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Part below doesn't matter. **I found out that I made a mistake and solving the equation like that isn't possible. We get 0 row.**

Thanks for asking me to write it in LaTeX, as working harder to write it, made me realize where I had gone wrong.

---

I have used $$P_i$$ to refer to a row i, that I will be doing the operation on.

To simplify I firstly used equation 1 to eliminate the first variable of equation 3.
Than used that one to eliminate the second one of equation 2. After which I used equation 2 and 3 to eliminate first two variables of equation 1.
If I than used that, I could get row echelon form with a bit of rearanging.
Like that isn't it possible to solve it and even get inverse matrix?

What am I missing, or had done wrong?

Thanks for help, because here I really don't understand why it's possible, given that with third row we actually hadn't added new information to the system, so it shouldn't be possible to get a solution that didn't exist before.

EDIT: Added LaTeX Matrices.

Comment: (1) I am unable to read some of the numbers in the Image. Might be great if you can use MathJAX to write it out (2) When we can eliminate a row , it might not imply no Solution , rather it might imply multiple Solutions too !

Comment: If row one plus two two equals row three then the rows are linearly dependent. Therefore, the determinant is zero and the matrix is not invertible. When you reduce such a matrix, multiply $-1$ by each of rows one and two and add them to row three. That will make row three zero. If the third row must equal a non-zero value then there will be no solution.

Comment: Please use MathJax. It will help you too.

Comment: With the rank of the matrix $A$ and the rank of the matrix $A$ concattenated with the vector $b$ , you can determine whether $Ax=b$ has a solution and if so, whether it is unique. If the ranks do not coincide, there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

try solving it like this:
$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  3&4&-2&0\\
  -4&1&-1&0\\
  -1&5&-3&1
\end{array}
\right] $ $\overset{R_2=R2-R3}\to$
$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  3&4&-2&0\\
  -3&-4&2&-1\\
  -1&5&-3&1
\end{array}
\right] $ $\overset{R_1=R1+R2}\to$
$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0&0&0&-1\\
  -3&-4&2&-1\\
  -1&5&-3&1
\end{array}
\right] $

now we get the vector
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
*
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix} = -1
$

$0*x_1 + 0*x_2 + 0*x_3 = -1$ $\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\,\,$
$0=-1$

which is a contradiction

that's why this set of equations doesn't have a solution.